# Managing Prices

Tags: price, simple-product, price-rules, catalog-rules, pricing

Hi to everyone!

I have to create a new Online Store in Magento 1.9.1.1.

For the type of Products, almost all the Products will be Configurable Products with a lot of Simple Products associated.

The big problem is to manage the Prices.

*On a previous Store I used SCP (Simple Configurable Product by Organic) but I've read that it is not reccomanded cause it is not supported from a long time and it can cause a lot of problems.*

- I have to set all the Prices in the Simple Product ignoring the Price of the Configurable Product (this because there isn't a rule that allow me to use the "Super product attributes configuration")
- I have to insert the Price of the Manufacturer Price List
- For some Manufacturer I have to apply a Discount / Increase depending on the Country of the Customer
- Some Manufacturer cannot be sold in some Country

To Manage this Situation, I think something like this:

**Simple-Product-Pricing** (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html) instead of SCP
**Catalogue Rules** (Modified to allow negative value for increase the Price List)
**Zone Pricing** (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zone-pricing.html) to Manage the Discount for each Country
**Restrict Product Country** (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/restrict-product-country.html) or **Shipping Restrictions** (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-restrictions-by-amasty.html) to disable some Manufacturer to some Countries.
What do you think? It is a good Solution or there is a better way? Can anyone suggest me another way or another extensions to manage this Situation?
Thanks to everyone